# Verilog How to change wire by bit with clock?

Tags: verilog, hdl, vivado

```
module clks(
    input clk,
    output [15:0] led
    );
    
    wire div2, div4, div8;
    reg [2:0] count = 0;
    assign div2 = count[0];
    assign div4 = count[1];
    assign div8 = count[2];
    always @(posedge clk) count = count + 1;
endmodule
```

How can I turn on each led (I have 15 leds) using clock?
I'm really having trouble finding helpful resources online

```
initial begin
        case({count})
        2'b00:
            led = 15'b000000000000001;
        2'b01:
            led = 15'b000000000000010;
        ...

        endcase
    end
```

This didn't work.
Or could I do something like this?

```
led = led + 1;
```

Comment: If the clock is running fast, you will not be able to see the change.  The clock must be running at ~100Hz for a human to see the difference.  You might be able see a brightness difference, but not if the clock is >1MHz.

Answer (score 2):

In your sample code above, you defined count as 3 bits, but your case statements are 2 bits wide. Also, you don't want the initial statement, rather use an always statement.

```
always @ (count)
begin
case(count)
3'b000 : led = 15'b000_0000_0001;
3'b001 : led = 15'b000_0000_0010;
...
endcase
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that 'by using clock' means changing the led every clock cycle, right? Also it looks like you are trying to encode the led sequentially. In this case you can do the following:

1. you need to reset your lead to an initial value, sey `15'b1`;
2. every clock cycle you can just shift it left by one. You should not do it in an initial block (though there is a technical way to do so). Use always blocks:

Here is an example:

```
module clks(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output reg [15:0] led
    );

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset == 1) 
         led <= 15'b1;
      else
         led <= led << 1;
   end
endmodule
```

In the above case '1' will travel through all bits of led over 15 clock cycles once. 'led' will become '0' after this. You have to make sure that it becomes '1' again if you want to continue in cycles.

Another possibility is to initialize 'led' in the always block, but it is not always synthesizable. YOu do not need a reset signal here.

```
initial led = 15'b1;
always @(posedge clk) led <= led << 1;
```